# Slider DIV with unknown link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, slideshow

I have created a slideshow but for some reason when I am clicking on the image to go to a next slide (as it should do) it takes it to another URL on a website I am creating.

I cant seem to find how I have managed to create a link to the page when clicking on it?

Here is the link to the page.

http://lichfieldrooms.uk/gallery.html

Comment: your `<div id="hero">` is wrapped in `<a href="contact.html">` so it will redirect to other page

Comment: Sorry just managed to close the </a> to end the link attribute.

Comment: yes your link for `contact` is broken `><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</li>` it is broken it should be `<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

you `<a>` for all in navigation is broken you have not closed them so i think thats was causing the issue

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</li>
  <li>
    Rooms
    <ul>
      <li><a href="single.html">Single Bedroom</li>
      <li><a href="double.html">Double Bedroom</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</li>
  <li><a href="calendar.html">Check Availability</li>
  <li><a href="reservations.html">Terms</li
  ><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

it should be

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>Rooms
        <ul>
            <li><a href="single.html">Single Bedroom</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="double.html">Double Bedroom</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="calendar.html">Check Availability</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="reservations.html">Terms</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Has been sorted! :)